# ClientException Client error: `GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?prettyPrint=false` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response:

Tags: laravel, google-api

when I wanna login with google account, I receive this error,

> ClientException Client error: `GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?prettyPrint=false`
> resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response:  
>  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1,
> minimum-scale=1, w (truncated...) in RequestException.php line 113

```
 public function redirectToProvider()
    {
        return Socialite::driver('google')->redirect();
    }



    public function handleProviderCallback()
    {
        $social_user = Socialite::driver('google')->user();

        $user = User::whereEmail($social_user->getEmail())->first();


        if( ! $user ) {
            $user = User::create([
                'name' => $social_user->getName(),
                'email' => $social_user->getEmail(),
                'password' => bcrypt($social_user->getId())
            ]);
        }

        if($user->active == 0) {
            $user->update([
                'active' => 1
            ]);
        }

        auth()->loginUsingId($user->id);
        return redirect('/');
    }
```

Comment: have you set your auth credentials properly, it seems the credentials you send are not verified as correct by google apis

Comment: does [this](https://medium.com/employbl/add-login-with-google-to-your-laravel-app-d2205f01b895) shown in blog, works for you

Comment: Thanks a lot, I used this site   and change my code in GoogleProvider.php like this , green sentences are correct  https://github.com/laravel/socialite/pull/283/files

Comment: You can post what worked out for you in steps in the answer so that anyone who comes here for help can follow your answer

Answer (score 0):

From what i can see, you need to pass a token.

https://laravel.com/docs/master/socialite#retrieving-user-details

Answer (score 0):

This is solution for this problem. I found it from this website.

> https://github.com/laravel/socialite/pull/283/files
> I Update GoogleProvider.php in my project. Comment sentences have to update.
> GoogleProvider.php:

```
   protected function getUserByToken($token)
    {
//        $response = $this->getHttpClient()->get('https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?', [
                $response = $this->getHttpClient()->get('https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo/v2/me?', [
            'query' => [
                'prettyPrint' => 'false',
            ],
            'headers' => [
                'Accept' => 'application/json',
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$token,
            ],
        ]);

        return json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function mapUserToObject(array $user)
    {
        return (new User)->setRaw($user)->map([
//            'id' => $user['id'], 'nickname' => array_get($user, 'nickname'), 'name' => $user['display Name'],
//            'email' => $user['emails'][0]['value'], 'avatar' => array_get($user, 'image')['url'],
            'id' => $user['id'], 'nickname' => array_get($user, 'nickname'), 'name' => $user['name'],
            'email' => $user['email'], 'avatar' => array_get($user, 'picture'),
        ]);
    }
```